# copy data form sqlserver database to access database and vice versa

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012, ado

I have built a program by ms access as a front and save DATA  IN sql server database. Also I have some local table in my program. 
My program is connected to sql server by connection string and i can read, write, delete and update data.Sometimes I need to copy result of a query to my local table into access and sometimes I want to append one of my access table to sql table

I have written a connection and tried to executed it like this:

```
Function CopyData()
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection    
Dim strServer, strDatabase, strUsername, strPassword As String
    Dim strConnectionString As String
    strServer = "10.25.2.120"
    strDatabase = "dbKala"
    strUsername = "javid"
    strPassword = "1234"

    strConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & strServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & strDatabase & ";User ID=" & strUsername & ";Password=" & strPassword & ";"

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
    cn.CommandTimeout = 0
    cn.Open
   cn.Execute "INSERT INTO GetTelServer Select * FROM dbo.telefone"
End Function
```

but data isn't copied from sql to access and show me a message about invalid object my access table
I need to help me how to copy a query from sql to access table and vice verse

Comment: Please provide full code, especially how you initialize `cn`.

Comment: Also, what does *My program is connected to sql server by connection string* mean? Do you have linked tables?

Comment: I use ms access as a front and my database is sql server and I have not linked tables

Comment: excuse me. I edited codes on top

Answer (score 1):

This task would be a lot easier with linked DAO.Tables, but that needs proper ODBC-Driver for SQL-Server.

If Ms-Access and SQL-Servers bitness match (x64) you can try using [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on SQL-Server to access Ms-Access tables from there.

E.g

```sql
INSERT INTO SqlServerTable (SqlServerField) SELECT AccessField FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',  
      'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\SAMPLES\Northwind.mdb';  
      'admin';'',AccessTable);
```

If bitness doesn't match, you have to create 2 different connections and use recordsets (or Action-Query for insert)

One rs is to select the data, second is for inserts:

```vb
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn2 As ADODB.Connection, rs2 As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

Set cn2 = New ADODB.Connection
cn2.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Path\To\AccessDb;"

Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT SqlServerField FROM SQLSERVERTable")

Set rs2 = cn2.Execute("SELECT AccessField FROM AccessTable")

Do Until rs2.Eof
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("SqlServerField").Value = rs2.Fields("AccessField").Value
    rs.Update
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
rs2.Close
cn.Close
cn2.Close
```

Of course the fields data-types have to be compatible.